# How do I load a specific page as initial page in Flatlist in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flatlist

Suppose I have more than 100 data. Now when implementing Flatlist the initial page that loads is the first item from the data. Now my question is how do I load a specific data 50th data and still be able to scroll up or down.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with the `function-based` approach, you need to add

```js
const flatListRef = useRef(null);
```

In `useEffect()`, focused scroll to specific index with `scrollToIndex()` function.

```js
setTimeout(() => flatListRef.scrollToIndex({ animated : true, index : DATA[50] }), 500);
//replace DATA and add anything to index you want to focus
```

And in `return()`,

```js
<FlatList
    ref={ flatListRef }
    data={DATA}
    ...
/>
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

FlatList has a prop called `initialScrollIndex`, check it [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#initialscrollindex)